# How do I initialize a AES67 audio stream with PTPv2 clock within a Java client sending audio?

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming

I have a Java client application that should speak to a virtual AES soundcard. I know the AES67 is encoded in linear PCM over IP/UDP/RTP, so I'm especially keen to understand the setup of the PTPv2 clock.

Answer (score 0):

ptp is used to synchronize clocks,with PTP it is possible to achieve accuracy in the sub-microseconds range (in NTP is milliseconds)
the timestamp in the RTP packet you crate is **based on the PTP clock**,so its affects on the latency

**ptp synchronion:**

Step 1: Prior to synchronizing, organize the clocks into a master-slave hierarchy (based on observing the clock property information contained in the clock property information contained in Announce messages)

Announce messages carry information used to establish the master-slave hierarchy; they are not used for synchronization

Step 2: Each slave synchronizes to its master using the delay request-response or peer delay mechanism, by exchanging messages with its master (and possibly with an upstream peer-topeer transparent clock, if one is present)

**how its work with AES67:**

first you need to Synchronize to the ptp clock,

send SDP message(with the multicast ip,ptp clock master mac,audio format...),
and then you start the streaming, you create RTP packet (with the PCM date) and send them to AES67 multicast ip 239.69.x.x